# why does my muscular endurance vary wildly?

Tags: muscle-endurance

I have a stable exercise routine, stable diet, and stable everything else I can think of.  Yet, within short amount of time, specific exercises muscle endurance drops wildly (and sometimes goes back up slowly).

Example:  calf raises on one foot, from heel down to full extension, warmed up but fully rested - my left calf, I used to be able to do around 25-30, but very quickly, within 10 days, this dropped to 10-15.  For no reason I can think of.

This is just an example, it can happen at any time with any muscle group.

When I observe during the repeats what happens seems to be, the "burn" period is gone. That is, used to be there is an extended period where I can feel my muscles progressively burn and burn more, until I can't repeat. But when the "drop" happens, then there is no "burn" period anymore, I do repeats fairly easily, and then suddenly, I can't do any more.

Is this just because, a human body is not a machine and I should just not worry about it.  Or is this an indication I am doing something wrong, diet, exercise, or whatever, perhaps something going wrong with my body??

I understand you may say, add X to your exercise, or something like that.  This is not really what my question is.  I like my routine, and it is stable and so I don't understand why there should be such drops in the first place. There shouldn't, not as fast anyway.  I want to know why.

Comment: In this 10 day period have you done some running or jumping? Have you increased the amount of calf raises you do?

Comment: @Andy this has nothing to do with calves, it was just an example. Same thing happens randomly for other muscle groups. No short-term activity or lack, causes this. This is a long term global cause and effect and I don't know the cause.

Comment: Is there anything that recently changed in your life like having a kid or a loss of sleep, or is this a more chronic issue that has been happening for years?

Comment: @EricWarburton no change of any kind to anything. Every now and then I experience a sudden drop in some muscle group endurance. Sometimes it slowly comes back, but not always.  Last time it was the left calf.

Comment: @EricWarburton I don't have kids that I am aware of :)

Comment: This is quite normal and good of you to notice. Who knows haha. If you use your willpower you can usually get the muscle to start burning and do more reps. I guess sometimes things aren't as "flammable" so you need to get the burn going before you start and during the workout. That's my experience. Good luck. In general you need to workout a body part more than once every 10 days though. Every 3 days or less is better.